# Why is my UV Square download not working on my cup?

Tags: uv, add-on, edit-mode, uv-image-editor, error

I have downloaded the uv squares zip and I'm trying to apply it to the cup. As you can see from picture 1, it worked on the handle, but when I tried to use it on the cup, it gave the error message you see in picture 2. Any help or direction toward help would be much appreciated. [image: The Uv square being applied to the handle and not the cup][image: the error message when I try to apply the uv square to the cup]